# UNIX shell script reading csv

Tags: unix, awk

I have a csv file. I would like to put the fields into different variables. Supposed there are three fields in each line of the csv file. I have this code:

```
csvfile=test.csv
while read inline; do
   var1=`echo $inline | awk -F',' '{print $1}'`
   var2=`echo $inline | awk -F',' '{print $2}'`
   var3=`echo $inline | awk -F',' '{print $3}'`
   .
   .
   .
done < $csvfile
```

This code is good. However, if a field is coded with an embedded comma, then, it would not work. Any suggestion? For example:

```
how,are,you
I,"am,  very",good
this,is,"a, line"
```

Comment: The code isn't good, it contains several bugs, deprecated constructs, and is the wrong approach to doing what you're trying to do plus trying to save the values in different variables is almost certainly a bad idea anyway. If you post concise, testable sample input and expected output we can help you.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a dedicated tool like [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/); short of that, you could use gawk with `FPAT`: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content

Comment: What do you want to do with the `var`s you have set? For each line the value changes, so I think you want to do something with them inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the perfect solution but it will work in your case.

```
[cloudera@quickstart Documents]$ cat cd.csv 
a,b,c
d,"e,f",g
```

File content

```
csvfile=cd.csv
while read inline; do


var1=`echo $inline | awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "*", $i) }1' | awk -F',' '{print $1}' | sed 's/*/,/g'`
var2=`echo $inline | awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "*", $i) }1' | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sed 's/*/,/g'`  
var3=`echo $inline | awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "*", $i) }1' | awk -F',' '{print $3}' | sed 's/*/,/g'`


echo  $var1 " " $var2 " " $var3 


done< $csvfile
```

Output :

```
[cloudera@quickstart Documents]$ sh a.sh 
a   b   c
d   e,f   g
```

So basically first we are trying to handle "," in data and then replacing the "," with "*" to get desired column using awk and then reverting * to "," again to get actual field value

Comment: I got errors when try this script:  
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to put the fields into variables? In my actual csv file, I have 15 fields on each line and have more than 8000 lines.

Comment: You can try to store echo $inline | awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "*", $i) }1' part in form of array  and then use them further

Comment: Hi Pat if above answer solves your query can you please upvote and mark it as answer